# Unity Dash and top toolbar won't open after updating to 12.10

Tags: unity-dash, 12.10

Today, I updated to Ubuntu 12.10. After re-starting, like the updater suggested, the toolbar on the top of the screen, and the dash won't load. I seem to be missing other features, as well, like alt>tab to switch windows, etc.

I am able to access the Terminal, by typing Ctrl>Alt>T, which is how I was bale to access Firefox.

How do I fix this problem?

**Edit: 10/20/12**

I resorted to completely re-installing Ubuntu. If someone finds a way to fix this problem *without* completely re-installing, please feel free to post it below.

**Edit: 5:18 PM on 10/19/12**

I am probably not the only one who has noticed this, but I just found out that Ubuntu works fine if booted into Gnome. The probalem seems to be with Unity, and people have been saying it's also a problem with ATI graphics cards.

I have tried many of the suggestions in the other threads that have been suggested, and nothing seems to work. Other idea's would be appreciated!

**Edit: 2:10 PM on 10/19/12**

As [Chris Carter](https://askubuntu.com/users/32548/chris-carter) suggested, I'm including the results of the teminal command `lspci` here is my graphics card info:

`01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS780M/RS780MN [Mobility Radeon HD 3200 Graphics]`

Comment: Do you have an ATI/AMD graphic card?

Comment: Yes. The sticker says "AMD Athlon X2 64"

Comment: That is your processor, open a terminal and include the results of `lspci` in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I am still trying to get my head around this myself.

I had the same problem after doing an upgrade myself and it appears that Ati have yet to add support for the latest x-server.

I myself ended up doing a clean install and although I now have a usable desktop it is not taking full advantage of the capabilities of my card. I have not attempted to install fglrx
as I am sure it will break my system.

There are others asking questions like this e:g [Radeon HD 2000, 3000, 4000 on Ubuntu 12.04.2 and higher: fglrx (legacy) unsupported, what to do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-12-10-quantal-fglrx-12-6-unsupported-what-to-do)

There is probably a way to uninstall fglrx properly to get to a usable system that someone more learned than I can explain.

Answer (score 1):

[12.10 Unity GUI Not Displaying](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202954/12-10-unity-gui-not-displaying)

the above url provide fixes for this depending the kind of cpu & gpu  you are using
for removing fglrx worked and restored the unity gui back !

Comment: Please refrain from posting two similar answers. Edit your original post to add details to it and remove the latter one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The exact same thing happened in my laptop, I have a discreet card, the Intel one that comes integrated with the processor and an nvidia card: GeForce GT520M Cuda 1GB.
I too noticed that I could log into gnome just fine.
I'll try removing any graphic card drivers (flgrx if it is there and the nvidia ones) and see if it takes off.

Comment: Well, @MAnju 's answer did the trick, I installed bumblebee and it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the `flgrx` and any `nvidia` in mine before it fixed the problem.  Removing just the `flgrx` didn't work for me.