# I just upgraded to 12.10 lost my side bar

Tags: 12.10

I just upgraded to 12.10 from 12.04 and now I don't have the side bar to access the dash tab.I have also lost the  bar at the top that shows the volume and internet connection.

Comment: Try logging in, press Ctrl+Alt+T, then put in this command:

"unity --replace", without the quotation marks.

Does Unity start?

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved this by creating a live cd, running it and choosing the option to reinstall without getting rid of my existing files and folders.
Everything is back and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at these links, might solve your problem:

- [Lost unity taskbars and window frames after upgrading from 12.04 LTS on a Dell Precision m4600 nVidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203418/lost-unity-taskbars-and-window-frames-after-upgrading-from-12-04-lts-on-a-dell-p/204378#204378)
- [12.10 Unity GUI Not Displaying](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202954/12-10-unity-gui-not-displaying)