# after installing nvidia-current via jockey on 12.10 i only see my desktop but not the unity interface

Tags: nvidia, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop does not show when I installed nvidia drivers!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers)

I also tryed to install via the [x-swat ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) but there are no quental packages yet.

how can i install `nvidia-current`

Comment: [Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop does not show when I installed nvidia drivers!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/ubuntu-12-10-desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have the same problem. How extremely disapointing.

By Running:
 
`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` 
and then 
`sudo apt-get update` 
 Warn that there are no quental packages yet.

Exactly like the original poster said.

If Anyone has a solution I am pretty desperate. The original drivers, make the text on my screen go all jumbled.

Cheers

Comment: Solved: At least for me. In my software center I did a search for linux headers. Thats where I saw that the linux headers 3.5.0-17 was not installed. After I installed that, I installed the nvidia driver, rebooted and voila it all works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

did U install this way ?

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

if U did U need a reboot and then

glxinfo | grep OpenGL

to control that it was installed corectly