# Ubuntu 11.20 launcher disappeared after installing Nvidia Driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop does not show when I installed nvidia drivers!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers)

Yesterday, I have installed and updated Nvidia driver from Ubuntu Software Center. After restarting my PC launcher disappeared like in screen:

[image]

I have restarted, updated and re-installed Unity. But it doesn't work for me. I think there is problem with graphic/nvidia configuration.With Nvidia 520M

Comment: What is 11.20? It is 12.10? Or 11.10?

Comment: @LordofTime Most likely the OP switched the 1 and 2; it seems to be more probable to typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try go to compiz settings manager.To install it run command

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

and check if ubuntu unity plugin is enabled

[image]

also check decorating windows is enabled in effects.
[image]

if not working you can try this

```
 setsid compiz --replace
```

and restart unity with

```
unity --replace
```

Comment: I have removed Nvidia (current) Driver from Software Center. It solved problem but I feel it's not updated driver which I'm using now?

Comment: without activated graphic proprietary drivers ubuntu works with open source drivers by default.If you want closed one  google how to install supported nvidia drivers downloaded directly from nvidia site.

Comment: I see but which one is better and updated? Nvidia seems to keep updated. But even I installed from Software Center there was big problem. I'm new with Ubuntu and afraid of possible problems after installing driver from nvidia.

Comment: I would try installing xswat updates to add ppa execute :              sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates ,
sudo apt-get update ,
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings ,from this tutorial http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/to-do-list-after-new-installation-of.html or else download close driver from nvidia site and google how to install it in 12.10 quantal.