# ubuntu 12.10 - nvidia gtx 550 ti proprietary drivers issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop does not show when I installed nvidia drivers!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers)

I have installed Ubuntu 12.1 and own the nvidia gtx 550 ti (no integrated video). Installed it just fine but the buttons and text seem to get scrambled if using the nouveau drivers I guess. I tried installing the proprietary drivers manualy and from the Additional Drivers tab in software sources but every time I do that after it restarts the menus and icons dissapear an the only way getting them back is to revert to the nouveau drivers. I've tried noumerous attempts ending up reinstalling it. Any help would be apreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are many threads regarding installing Nvidia drivers under Ubuntu 12.10.   While I've found the new distribution to be quite lacking in this regard (among others), here's what worked for me.

After installing (i.e., upgrading or fresh install)

1. Get all updates using the software updater and reboot as required
2. Run: `sudo apt-get install linux-source`
3. Run: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`
4. Run: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current updates`
5. Reboot... run nividia-settings to verify the driver is installed and the card is recognized.

This has worked on a machine with a GTX-460 and another with a GTS-250 card installed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to install recommended drivers ... dont use recent drivers ..

else

http://www.nvidia.in/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-in

use automatic driver finder it will find drivers for you !!

Comment: thank you for your reply, however i tried installing the recomended drivers and same result. I noticed when installing proprietary drivers the display changes to "laptop" with a smaller resolution. the terminal still works and anything i can open with shortcuts. but all i can see is the background.

Comment: ok i found what i had to do. first had to install the linux source and the linux generic headers and then updated the nvidia drivers