# How do I install NVIDIA GPU drivers properly?

Tags: nvidia

Having found a lot of different questions on Ask Ubuntu regarding NVIDIA graphics drivers installation generating various issues and problems on Ubuntu systems - I do want to know:

**What do Ubuntu users have to care about when installing the NVIDIA graphics drivers?**

Explanation:

Being aware that this topic already has many good questions and answers it actually always stays up-to-date. One example : Many new notebooks come with hybrid graphics and Optimus support so they depend on proprietary NVIDIA drivers being installed to function properly but most of all existing posts point to [xorg-edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) which doesn't provide the drivers anymore since ubuntu [Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) was introduced, so many old answers are mostly obsolete or wrong.

Comment: It is not too broad. We have another question "How to install Nvidia drivers" with very high voted wrong answers. Like installing from .run files. It makes no sense to close it as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @Pilot6 what is wrong with this http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433?

Comment: @Tim If Luis updates the answer, I will be the first to vote to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Pilot6 you have editing privs... Anyone can edit it. And whether that is up to date or not, this is still a duplicate...