# NVIDIA card suddenly changed resolution and does not allow login

Tags: nvidia

Some time ago, I had installed `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.30.run`

It seemed to work.  Certainly I was able to login and graphics was working.
All of a sudden, One day I rebooted and the screen resolution was different.  My login does not work.  I logged in under console and found that the reason appears to be the following message in `dmesg`:

```
NVRM: The NVIDIA GPU 0000:01:00.0 (PCI ID: 10de:1381)
NVRM: installed in this system is not supported by the 304.128 NVIDIA Linux driver release.....
```

Does this mean the newer driver suddenly disappeared?  I really don't know what 304.128 is, but it sounds old.  I will install the latest, but this makes me extremely suspicious of my computer.

Note that when I boot into Windows everything works fine in 3800x2160 x 30Hz mode.  That is definitely the NVIDIA driver under Linux, and the hardware does not appear to be the problem.

Comment: What I see is you installed version 352.30, but Ubuntu is now using 304.128. I would definitely try either reinstalling what you had before or installing the latest.

Comment: It could have been a regular kernel update. You have to re-run NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.30.run every time that happens. 304.128 is one of the legacy drivers Nvidia maintains for older graphics cards. It is a good idea to uninstall it, if it is installed.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea kernel updates would invalidate my driver!

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/680825/how-do-i-install-nvidia-gpu-drivers-properly

Answer (score 1):

Either due to a kernel update, or corruption, the NVIDIA driver I had manually installed seemed to evaporate.  Installing from the repository should be a good way to keep it there:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

lists out the packages available, of which the best (at the time of writing) was:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

Note this is not the most recent driver, but it's one that is in standard repositories, so it will continue to get updated which is fine with me.