# Ubuntu 15.04 with GPU tesla k20 and GT610 Graphics card

Tags: gpu

Can anyone tell me how to get drivers for these GPU and Graphics card?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install NVIDIA GPU drivers properly?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/680825/how-do-i-install-nvidia-gpu-drivers-properly)

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and execute:

**Tesla K20 :**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

**GT610 :**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

---

Refer to this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/q/680825/338915) for more information.