# Nvidia driver for Dell Inspiron 14r 5420

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dell, intel-graphics, ivybridge

I install the Ubuntu 15.04 on my notebook Dell Inspiron 14r 5420, which have 2 GPU using the Intel® Ivybridge Mobile technology.

How I install the driver for the Nvidia GPU? The GPU on this notebook is the GeForce 630M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

install the **Long term supported NVIDIA driver version from Ubuntu repositories:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

or choose the **Latest NVIDIA driver version from Proprietary GPU drivers PPA:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
```

Refer to this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/q/680825/338915) for more information.

---

Additionally you can install `prime-indicator`
which will quickly let you switch between your Intel graphics and your GeForce 630M card :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install prime-indicator
```

[image: prime-indicator]

Prime-indicator and screenshot credit to [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html).