# Issues Updating Grub with Dual Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, updates

I was dual booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.04 (I installed Windows then Ubuntu), and when I used the software updater right after the Ubuntu install, it would freeze (window would dim) while updating grub 2. I was able to force quit and run software updater again, in which it would tell me to restart the computer and grub would work, but it just irks me that it wasn't installed smoothly.

I just reformatted my drive and installed only Ubuntu and there were no issues with updating. Anyone have any thoughts why?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has got nothing to do with dual booting, as long as you can boot Ubuntu and Windows.
The problem might have been occurring because the graphics card was not configured properly.
When you have NVIDIA graphics (especially on notebooks with Optimus) it is recommended to install the latest current stable drivers from the NVIDIA long-lived branch. - More information about how to do this you will find in the Q+A : [How do I install NVIDIA GPU drivers properly ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680825/how-do-i-install-nvidia-gpu-drivers-properly)

To avoid these kind of issues when installing Ubuntu : add the **nouveau.modeset=0** parameter (in case of NVIDIA graphics) to the end of the GRUB linux line when booting from install media.

Comment: My laptop is a Dell Latitude E6320, the graphics card is the integrated Intel HD 3000

Comment: @user461067 : So then you ran into a randomly occurring issue which does not have anything to do with dual booting - as you said the second Ubuntu installation attempt went smoothly ... :)