# Ubuntu 14, how install nvidia driver without crash?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I installed Ubuntu 14 on my computer and i have an nvidia Gtx 660.

If i keep the default driver from xserver xorg, i have lag and freeze, So i tried to install a nvidia driver.

I tried the last version (340+), and When i reboot, i have an error APCI PROBE FAILED, and only thing i can do is to reinstall another Time ubuntu.

I tried other version like 304, but its the same, i always crash my system on reboot.

What can i do ? How can i install my nvidia driver ?

I already Check on Google and hère but i have no found a solution... Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and :

1. Remove all old Nvidia & Nvidia related packages :

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge libvdpau-va-gl1 bumblebee* nvidia*
   ```
2. Install `nvidia` driver :

   **Long term supported version :**

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
   ```

   or **Latest version :**

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
   ```

Refer to this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/q/680825/338915) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the Ubuntu help page (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia). I never had problems with NVIDIA drivers and Ubuntu. Usually the card is detected and the OS gives you the option to use the NVIDIA driver. Maybe you did this yet, but as you don't say anything about how you tried to install the drivers, I supposed that you tried to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

NVIDIA has fixed many issues and improved their drivers a lot since the release of drivers 346.

So install the latest NVIDIA drivers supporting GTX 660 from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA.

Before you install new drivers uninstall all NVIDIA related software you have installed before.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Then install the latest current stable NVIDIA drivers from the short-lived branch by executing :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 
sudo reboot
```

In case you are using a notebook with a hybrid graphics solution install Optimus support as well.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

When experiencing problems add **nouveau.modeset=0** to the end of the linux line before booting into Ubuntu (press "e" in GRUB menu entry - add the parameter - then press F10 ).