# Linux kernel 3.5.0-18 update is not working with NVIDIA driver 304.60

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, display

I have Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit and a Nvidia card GT430 and installed 304.60 Linux driver manually and it worked beautifully until the latest Ubuntu update which got modified to 3.5.0-18 Kernel. Everything has gone: launcher, windows I can't move them it got USELESS.  I tried to run the previous kermel 3.5.0-17 with which the driver was working well. I gto the same desktop. USeless - So the problem is something else I guess but it has to do with the update that's for sure- Any idea what to do? Now I have to switch back to Windows 7 which I don't want in order to able to work until an update will come up.

Comment: Every manually installed driver must be rebuilt against each new kernel. Simply boot in recovery mode and re-run the Nvidia driver installer.

Comment: @mikewhatever - How does one do that? I'm similarly afflicted, but have no idea what commands to run.

Comment: But what if the driver is not compatible with the Kernel?

Comment: @Konklone Run the same command you've used to install it, just from the recovery mode, in other words `sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.60.run`.

Comment: @JanosFejos Nvidia drivers usually have very good kernel compatibility. What makes you think it's incompatible with 3.5.0-18? Have you tried rebuilding yet?

Comment: @mikewhatever Yeah you're right the problem wasn't only the driver though.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by following rft183's approach here:

[Desktop does not show when I installed nvidia drivers!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers/202587)

Basically, install the `linux-source` and `linux-headers-generic` packages, then reinstall the `nvidia-current-updates` package (it worked for me just by providing the `--reinstall` flag, I didn't need to remove the package). Then reboot.

Comment: Well it seems it got fixed But I'm not sure how. I followed the steps what @Konklone posted than I downloaded and reinstalled the latest Nvidia driver manually. I rebooted. It didn't get fixed right away than I thought: It has to do with Compiz and Unity too because both got crashed. So than I'm guessing I reset both Unity and Compiz but here is the thing: I don't really remember which command line was the curing pill. Unity --reset or Unity --replace ( --reset got deprecated) or Compiz --replace I don't know how but it got fixed for now.