# Unity problems after changing graphic card drivers

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, 12.10

The fan of my graphic card is very loud. I tried to install additional drivers for it. After rebooting my PC - to apply changes - unity won't show...
If I change the driver back to default unity shows up again after restart.

Graphic card: GeForce 9600 GT

Answer (score 0):

When you have the nvidia driver not active fire up a therminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T.

Then install the missing kernel package

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source 

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-18-generic
```

Reconfigure the graphic modules:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-current-updates
```

Activate the driver with the gui or:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

Restart the computer

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Nope... doesn't work. After rebooting Unity doesn't shows up anymore.

Comment: Try to remove the nvidia driver and reinstall it again, you remove the driver by typing: sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current

or

sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current-updates 

or

sudo apt-get remove nvidia-experimental-304

Comment: Currently I'm using the xserver-xorg-video-nouveau driver - the only one unity works with. So all those commands are useless.

Comment: It realy sounds like you hit the graphic headers bug, look at this question  http://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers/203692#203692

Comment: Nice :) Thanks, this helped a lot. I'm new to linux and already tried this couple days ago without success. But now I got a little bit used to all those terminal commands it worked out nicely.