# Fresh Ubuntu 12.10 install no desktop or wing bar

Tags: installation, 12.10

After a fresh installm of ubuntu 12.10 (complete erase) after logging in it appears i have no taskbar or much of anything, although i can still execute my terminal with CTRL+ALT+T. i looked around a little, seems i'm not the only person who has had this problem. 
I found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12303179#post12303179
From there, i found myself here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-updates/+bug/1068341

I followed precisely the instructions provided which were:

this problem is solved this way

Switch to a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F1).

```
Login as your username.

Install linux source (sudo apt-get install linux-source) and headers (sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic).

Uninstall nvidia driver - this depends on which version you installed (sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current or sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current-updates or sudo apt-get remove nvidia-experimental-304).

Reinstall nvidia driver (sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates).

If it successfully installs, restart the computer (sudo shutdown -r now).
```

Source
[Desktop does not show when I installed nvidia drivers!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/ubuntu-12-10-desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers)

I have rebooted, and i am still having the exact same problem.
so i back at square one.
can someone help me please? this is my room mates computer and i told him i was "fixing" it and now i feel like i've ruined it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: How about you just uninstall the nvidia drivers and restart?
You can install those once your desktop works after verifying which ones would work best with your card.

Answer (score 1):

After reading all the posts on here and thru google
this is the standard lines I type in my terminal after a new install 12.10 with nvidia cards, seems to work
bruce

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current nvidia-current-updates nvidia-experimental-304

sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current 
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current-updates

sudo apt-get install linux-source 
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current


sudo reboot
```

Comment: Hello Bruce, thank you very much for your reply.
i followed your instructions exactly, and upon reboot, my desktop is still blank. is it perhaps because im not sure of the card? I'm on a Dell Dimension 3000 desktop PC.