# 12.10 partial upgrade from 12.04 now the gui doesnt appear

Tags: 12.10, gui

A partial upgrade was completed from 12.04 to 12.10.

i can log in but after that nothing happens.  no response to the alt keys unless its the alt and Sysrq or ctrl Alt Del.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please give more details on the state of the OS after your login - Do you have a blank screen, or are you actually logged in? What Desktop Environment do you use? Does [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/202587/98085) help you?

Comment: i am logged in.  Unity is the environment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe compiz (or its many plugins, specifically windows decorations) failed to start after the upgrade. Try to start the ccsm tool and enable them using alt+f2 if you are able to.