# Ubuntu 12.10: black screen after installing nvidia-current

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, display-manager

COMPUTER: Macbook pro 7'1 (mid 2010)
GRAPHIC CARD: NVIDIA 320M

Today, after a fresh install of Ubuntu Quantal Quetzal, I installed the suggested nvidia drivers from terminal by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

and then:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

But when I rebooted, after chosing Ubuntu from the boot loader, the screen was black and there was nothing I could do...

How can I fix this?

---

Thank you roadrm for your helpful answer, but I still cannot boot into a usable system even editing the kernel and adding the nomodeset string :( I managed to boot the 3.5.0-17, but my default kernel is the 3.5.0-25 so this doesn't help... I should probably add to the informations that before installing the nvidia-current I also entered the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install Linux-source
```

And

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

In order to give The correct headers for the driver :(

Comment: This has been answered many times. Check out [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers) and see if it works for you

Comment: Leonardo - if you have lost your account login details - please reregister your account and click the link at the bottom of the page to ask for your old and new accounts to be merged.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a stab in the dark, but try this:

- Boot the system, hold left-shift to get the grub menu
- Press "e" to edit the kernel command line, and add "nomodeset", see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) for more details on how to do this.
- This should hopefully bring you to a usable system, even if only in console mode.
- Now for the fun part. I *suspect* you're running into a bug that causes kernel modules to fail building due to missing kernel headers (bug report is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/1070427)). To install the kernel headers, do

  sudo apt-get install linux-headers linux-headers-3.5.0-25-generic

Replace 3.5.0-25 by your running kernel version (use the uname -a command to see this).

- Once the new headers are installed, do `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`.
- Closely watch the console output. If you see a message like this:

  Building only for 3.5.0-17-generic
  Building for architecture x86_64
  Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
  kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

  it means the module wasn't compiled due to lack of kernel headers. This will tell you the version of the headers your system is expecting.
- Once you get the modules correctly built, reboot normally and things should hopefully work.