# How install Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, kernel

Today I performed fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04.
After this I tried to install Nvidia graphics driver.
I used 2 methods:

1. [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)
2. http://falkvinge.net/2013/02/15/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal/

Both of them with the same result. Black screen with some text on it.
I saw that many ubuntu users have the same issue. Nvidia drives just broke the system.
Not sure If I can say that Ubuntu is so user friendly system if you just press install in Addidtional drivers tab and you can say goodbye to your OS.

How this can be fixed? Does anybody know some other ways?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Not sure If I can say that Ubuntu is so user friendly system if you just press install in Additional drivers tab and you can say goodbye to your OS." This is only true if you do not know how to fix things ;-) (see for instance: http://askubuntu.com/questions/265233/ubuntu-12-10-black-screen-after-installing-nvidia-current ) Besides that you say there is text somewhere. I believe it probably is essential to provide us with that text. (it makes answering a lot easier).

Comment: This appears to be a bug that needs to be reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug with nvidia on the 3.8.0-19-generic kernel, a workaround is to use the mainline kernel

Here is a easy installer/updater for the mainline kernel
https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater
then the nvidia driver should work

The bug results in some times not booting and broken HDMI audio

Comment: Thanks guys to ur answers. I run script proposed by GM-Script-Writer-62850 and it fixed the issue. Thanks a lot. Still can't consider Ubuntu user friendly if Canoncial can release OS with a bug like this. U have to be a really good IT professional to make ur system boot after simple procudeure of Driving installations prposed by OS itself. Really dissapointing issue.

Comment: The sad thing is the at least half of the dev cycle was boring, literally everything was good then a week before it goes live, this bug showed up, they decided it was not worth delaying the release over, it should be fixed when updates are installed after the fix comes through

Comment: TY GM-Script-Writer

Comment: **@GM-Script-Writer-62850** I'm having similar issues with Intel B43 Express/GMA-4500 since **3.8.0-19**. This is no better in **3.8.0-22**. *When is the fix due?*

Comment: no idea figured it would be fixed by now, you could use saucy's (ubuntu 13.10) kernel, there may be a back-ported kernel available, otherwise there is the mainline kernel

Comment: Is this still a problem? I have kernel 3.8.0-30 installed and I'm still having problems with nvidia drivers. Should I try this script?

Comment: go for it, i suggest using this in in step 4 ``KernelUpdateChecker -v 3.9 -r saucy``

Answer (score 0):

I just did a fresh install of 13.04 today because the upgrade crashed my nvidia.

After the fresh install, I just followed the bumblebee wiki page instructions and nvidia is performing absolutely fine.

Best,