# Ubuntu 13.04 upgrade : problems with NVIDIA graphic drivers

Tags: nvidia, 13.04

I have a made a clean upgrade from 11.04 to 13.04 in my Acer Desktop with graphic nVidia GeForce 7100 / nForce 630i/integrated/SSE2. 
With 11.04 I had no problems.
Now if I use Nouveau graphic drivers the system is very slow. The same with NVIDIA 173 drivers.
Instead with drivers 304 and 304 updates it does not boot.
I have to go through GRUB : Ubuntu Recovery Mode and then RESUME. In this way the system boots and works fine.

I think the problem is in the graphic driver . But my question is : what is different when instead of a straight boot I go throuh Recovery Mode/Resume ?
If  I cannot have a good graphic driver can I make this difference ,let say , permanent ?
Many thanks if someone can help.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285944/how-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)