# Help needed! Nvidia/Intel graphics driver installation problem on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10. My PC isn't auto detecting my drivers, I've tried installing the graphic drivers from the additional drivers section, but it shows nothing.

when I open up the "About this computer" tab, I see that my graphics driver is UNKNOWN and my experience is STANDARD.
After referring to a lot of forums, I saw that I had to run this command,

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

I see this output

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 630M] (rev a1)
```

I have tried downloading nvidia's graphic driver file, but it's a .run file and I don't know how to install it.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try change the drivers via GUI mode? You can do it via Software Center. Press menu "Edit" > "Software sources" and then the tab "Additional Drivers". It should offer you a easy way to change or update drivers detected.

Comment: I did, but that doesn't work, drivers weren't detected. it says no proprietary drivers are in use.

Comment: If this is one of those hybird cards, I think this is a duplicate of the following: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work/36936#36936 If not a hybird card, this similar question and answer should help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think it's a hybrid card, and I  have tried the solution, but it doesn't seem to help. Any more help would definitely be appreciated!

Comment: I think I could give you some instructions on how to use the *.run file via a TTY to install an nVidia-driver manually (which I do regularly, as the GUI options didn't work for me since 13.10 and installing the driver manually did). But the linked answer above warns against this as it seems. However, if you want to take the risk, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

See the Nvidia instructions:

> Installation instructions: Once you have downloaded the driver, change to the directory containing the driver package and install the driver by running, as root, sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.17.run

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You have **hybrid graphics card, Intel+nVidia.** Intel for power saving and nVidia for performance. I solved the problem and answered it in here: 
[in here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350407/cant-use-nvidia-gpu/350472#350472)

*The process worked for my laptop and tested on Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10*