# Can´t use Nvidia GPU?

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, gpu

Could somebody please explain to me how I use my `740M GPU` from Nvidia instead of the `HD4000` form Intel?

I am using Ubuntu `13.04` on a Asus N56VB

Comment: Have you installed the NVIDIA driver?

Comment: The driver can't be installed as usual. See my answer, there is how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have hybrid graphics. Means that you have two graphics cards, Intel HD for power saving and nVidia for performance. You have to install Bumblebee to install nVidia graphics driver. Here is how to install bumblebee: ( https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation )

You need to open your terminal and enter the commands below.

If on 12.04.3, replace `linux-headers-generic` with `linux-headers-generic-lts-raring`.

(not needed for 13.10 Saucy and newer)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

Enable the Universe and Multiverse repositories (for bumblebee and nvidia packages respectively).

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Bumblebee using the default proprietary nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee virtualgl linux-headers-generic
sudo reboot
```

**For Ubuntu 14.04:**

Run these commands in terminal

> sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus nvidia-331

Now you have to install `Bumblebee GUI` to manage apps to be opened using nVidia. Here is the instructions: ( [How to install Bumblebee-UI (GUI) in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134594/how-to-install-bumblebee-ui-gui-in-ubuntu-12-04) )

Install Python App Indicator:

```
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
```

Install Git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Make a directory for git:

```
mkdir git && cd git
```

Check out the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bumblebee-ui.git
cd bumblebee-ui
sudo ./INSTALL
```

Go to Startup Applications and add `/usr/local/bin/bumblebee-indicator`

Now reboot again.

Comment: This actually works in many scenarios.