# Switch video card

Tags: video, nvidia-optimus

How to switch the integrate video card Intel to discrete video card nVidia, I fond a solution on askubuntu with Ubuntu Control Centre but E: Unable to locate package ucc. Exists other else methods for switching video cards?

Comment: I solved the problem and gave full instruction here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/350407/cant-use-nvidia-gpu/350472#350472">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switcheroo is what you're looking for, vga_switcheroo is the kernel mechanism that allows you to switch between GPUs (if you have Hybrid graphic system). Since linux 3.3, this is working again with NVIDIA Optimus (fix: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next-history.git/commit/?id=d099230cc355c485e556121c034b1fca5a5fd18b),

Here you can find everything you need to know about this feature: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Anyway, for NVIDIA Optimus, you can also use Bumblebee: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: Now I try Bumblebee

Comment: So? Is it working now?