# Ubuntu 12.04.3 drivers for Lenovo G500 with i3 3110M CPU

Tags: drivers, lenovo

I'm thinking in buying a Lenovo G500 with i3 3110M CPU, I asked Lenovo and they said they don't have drivers for Linux yet and seems G500 is not a certified hardware yet. But I'm pretty sure that there are lot of G500 owners who has already installed successfully Ubuntu 12.04.3 64bits, which drivers you used to install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I have Lenovo G500s. All drivers are included in the Linux Kernel. Only for the Graphics card, [use this trick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350407/cant-use-nvidia-gpu/350472#350472). But older Linux Kernel occurs problem with Ethernet driver. But if you update the kernel the driver will be automatically installed. If you use Ubuntu 13.04 or newer then the driver is pre-installed.