# I cant install nvidia drivers for gt635m on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lenovo

Last night I tried to install the nvidia drivers from the official site but the `.run` didn't work for some reason.

So after it, I tried to install them with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` and other stuff like this. When I installed the driver with the `sudo` command my laptop boots into black screen and I can only accses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> function.

So I had to reinstall my PC again. Everything else is working correctly but I can't get this driver to work. And in additional drivers, I can only see the Wi-Fi adapter driver.

Also I've tried the bumblebee thing, and it doesn't work as well.

How can I solve these?

I'm using

- Lenovo G580
- i7 processor
- 6GB ram
- Nvidia 635GT

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the output of: `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: You may have this problem. watch this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/350407/cant-use-nvidia-gpu/350472#350472