# Menus don't show after an upgrade

Tags: menu

I'm having this problem after an automatic upgrade, where the only thing that is correctly loaded is the background image.

Another user experienced the exact same problem, though the cause is different (this was his post: [Desktop does not show when I installed nvidia drivers!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers)).

Consider that previously to this, I used Repair Mode, but it didn't work at all! Once I load Ubuntu in Normal Mode, the same thing happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Reptile, and welcome to askubuntu. Thanks for the information; hopefully it will be useful to people. However, askubuntu is more of a question and answer site rather than a forum, so please create an "answer" from the answer part of your question, and edit the question to remove this part. (Then accept your own answer.) Cheers!

Comment: Hi Sparhawk. I edited my post, based on your request. Hope it's OK now.

Comment: Great, that's terrific! +1 for both to hopefully get you over the permission humps… (The only other thing is to accept your own answer with the tick on the left of the answer, but I'm not sure if there is a mandatory pause before you can do it.) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I used these commands to fix everything and it worked. So, here are the steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Login with your username and password
3. Run this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
   ```
4. Then restart the system writing this:

   ```
   sudo shutdown -r now
   ```

That would be all.

I'm not a programmer, and it's the first time I write here, so, in case something is wrong, feel free to correct or improve my message if you're an expert.

Thanks.