# No panels or menus after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: unity, upgrade, system-installation

I just upgraded my System to 14.04.

After restarting when the update was finished I did not see any menu bars or panels.

Right clicking and opening a terminal via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> is not possible. However I can access the terminal via <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. I already tried out installing the unity-desktop again but it didn't change anything .

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: did you try to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`? Because you mentioned you were trying to reinstall `unity-desktop` there's no package `unity-desktop` do `sudo install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and tell if it does anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this didn't change anything. Could there by a problem with nvidia?

Comment: please tell me the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`

Comment: or just what graphics cards + drivers u have, you can use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ for long terminal output - you can also use `lshw` or [`lshw-gtk`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lshw-gtk/) to get the info

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears This may be relevant to you,

Comment: @JohnnyD.As I'm writting from my Laptop I can just type in the Output:

Comment: 1:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300] : NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce G210m] [10de:0a74] (rev a1)
!:00.1 Audio device [0403] : Nvidia Corpotation High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0be3] (rev a1)
@ChrisCarter I enabled the unitiy plugin and restarted my computer but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I have had this issue but with an AMD video card and know I came across others with Nvidia so I found this http://askubuntu.com/a/202587/32548

Comment: @ChrisCarter After typing in sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` I got the message:
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package from another source. 'linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic' has no installation candidate'

Comment: it seemed like you typed not full output that I asked, I can't see `driver in use` option this should be at the end of the output. I reproduced your problem on my PC managing to remove/disable all panels and got it back, but I need to know that last option from the output `kernel driver in use` because you might experience something different

Comment: answer my comment, then I'll walk you through.

Comment: @JohnnyD. I typed in lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA and the only output I get is the one I posted above. Should I try another command?

Comment: no this should do the trick, ok I'll write you an answer in couple of mins we'll figure it out on the way

Answer (score 7):

I tried reproducing your trouble by disabling Unity-plugin, after this resetting Unity or its settings didn't work. So, this what I've done trying to get it back:

install `Compiz Config Settings Manager` if you don't have it:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Now, you have to go to `Compiz Config Settings Manager` and enable `Unity-plugin` when Compiz manager opened navigate to `Unity-plugin` or just type in search `Unity` then click on it and on the left put a `tick` wait a sec it should get back.

How to get to `Compiz Manager` and `Terminal` without Unity interface when nothing's responding even pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ? There's always the way to get around, for example press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> you'll get `System Monitor` navigate to `File Systems` you'll get listed with your HDD subsections and simply click twice on `Home section` now you should get `Nautilus` running. Navigate to `/` and hit the search bar just type `Terminal` now you can launch `Terminal` from search result, the same way type `CompizConfig` and you should get Compiz Manager launcher.

What other ways you can try using `Terminal` try to `purge` `Unity`:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge unity
```

Now reinstall it along with `ubuntu-desktop` simply type and run:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

This should automatically install and put Unity back on, you'll be able to see the packages that are going to be installed, if not run:

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

After all may require reboot, didn't occur to me.

if you want or need to reset Unity on Ubuntu 14.04 you can use `Unity Tweak Tool` to do so, if you don't have it installed:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

and to reset run:

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

Alternatives, all this stuff I wrote should definately work if everything else is fine including video drivers and you can try it in addition with `Gnome` for example, simply install `gnome-shell`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

now reboot, and then at the login screen choose `gnome-shell` and log in, if everything is ok, it should work 100%, if not, the problem is not only in Unity, it might refer to video drivers issues as well.

These are all ways that I could figure out, so good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Everything went well until sudo apt-get install unity. I restarted my computer and nothing changed. So I was trying to install the unity-tweak-tool. But as I was trying that I got an error. It says:
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libeoffice-core: Depends: libreoffice-common ( > 1:4.2.3~rc3) but it is not going to be installed
libreoffice-ogltrans: Depends:libreoffice-commin but it is not going to be installed.
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install'.

Comment: I tryed that line an some things were installed but after that I got the same error message as I was trying to install the unity-tweak-tool again. apt-get dist-upgrade doesn't work as well and I'm not able to install gnome-shell. Do you have any idea what is going on?

Comment: follow this http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Thank you !  the unity-tweak-tool approach worked for me. ahhhhh finally pulled me out of this 2-hour headache!

Comment: The unity-tweak-tool worked for me too. Thanks

Comment: The unity-tweak-tool doesn't persist the changes after rebooting

Comment: as you can see this answer was voted up and helped lots of users... if it doesn't work for you probably your issue is something else... try to create your own question describing an issue that led this to happen and tag this thread to your question as what you have tried.