# Repair Unity panel & dash after compiz settings change

Tags: unity, compiz, kde, unity-dash, panel

I played a little with the compiz settings and the Unity top panel and dash disappeared.

They aren't loaded anymore. I tried [all suggestions posted here](https://askubuntu.com/q/17381/148451) but I had no success.

Temporary I installed `kubuntu-desktop` (KDE) that runs fine, but **I want Unity back**.

How can I do this?

---

### Solution

I posted my solution [here, as answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/471616/148451).

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you having this problem with?

Comment: @ElderGeek I am using 14.04 64bit.

Comment: Try running unity under a guest account and see whether it will work...

Comment: @Parto I added a new user and seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Parto please convert your comment to an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ElderGeek That was a test to check whether the issue is global or only affecting his account. As it turns out, his local unity config files have an issue and from there he can try to repair as per the suggestions in the linked question.

Comment: @Parto I did the following steps: created a temp user, made a backup of my original user files, deleted my original user (including the files), created a new admin with the original user name, then I copied the files from backup. Finally, I deleted the temp user. I would be happy to mark your answer if you added it. :-)

Comment: Maybe if I included your whole process as above.

Comment: I wrote the solution here also :-) http://askubuntu.com/questions/468204/no-panels-or-menus-after-upgrading-to-14-04/468431#468431

Comment: @JohnnyD. I also wrote my solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/471616/148451). I think it would be better to add answer on that question and mine and the another one to be marked as duplicate. +1, BTW. :-)

Comment: @IonicăBizău yep I agree.