# Blank desktop on Ubuntu 14.04 (menu missing)

Tags: unity, 14.04, .desktop

I had to shutdown my laptop unconventionally because of a programm error. Now if I startup I receive just the blue desktop wallpaper, without any menus. Can't even access the terminal. The right mouse button works and behaves normally and I can reach the settings. Something with gnome?

I already tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

from the command line without any success.

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: did you try CTRL+ALT+F1, log in, then `restart ui` (not sure, in ChromiumOS it works). Maybe you can just type `unity` and see if it boots.

Comment: @MRVaykadji `Unknown job: ui` - `unity` produces "WARNING: No Display variable set, setting it to :0" or someting

Comment: also http://askubuntu.com/questions/468204/no-panels-or-menus-after-upgrading-to-14-04/468431#468431

Answer (score -1):

In the user interface press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Then a command line shows. Type your login account and password.

Type the following commands.

```
 sudo apt-get install gnome
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo reboot
```

In the login screen change the Desktop Environment(DE) to GNOME. Then again back to Ubuntu default.

Please provide a feedback!

Comment: No, that didn't help. I had to reinstall it finally. Hope the bug get's solved.