# Stuck at Login Screen after Update (27.05.14)

Tags: unity, ati, login

As the title suggests, i am stuck at the login screen.
My system (ubuntu 14.04) was working fine and the problem appeared after i installed all updates and the following restart.

Basically i can log in, but unity won't load. I only see the standard wallpaper (not my personal) and i can use the mouse.

I tried several things...like

```
-install lightdm-gtk-greeter

-sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm

-unity --reset

-sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ (shows always wrong command...)

-enabling the unity plugin (the plugin was already enabled,so...)

-rm -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1
```

If i "startx" (via ALT-CTRL-F1) i get this output

```
.
.
.
Loading extension GLX
modprobe: FATAL: Module fglrx not found.
(WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:081:0:1) found
modprobe: FATAL: Module fglrx not found.
Loading extension FGLRXEXTENSION
Loading extension GLX
[glesx] __glESXExtensionInit: No GL ES2.0 capable screen found!
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:           Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                    Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:           Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                    Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to X server
```

My System:
Ubuntu 14.04 64bit
I5-3570k
ATI Radeon HD 7970 Ghz

Edit: With the old Kernel 3.13-0-24 it works...the newer 3.13.0-27 is the problem

Comment: you can try my workaround over here http://askubuntu.com/questions/468204/no-panels-or-menus-after-upgrading-to-14-04/468431#468431 also did you try to reconfigure/reset `X` server `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`? Or to reinstall your video card driver? This could also happen if you're not using the proprietary video drivers.

Comment: @user285911 Do you have the proprietary AMD driver installed? If yes, then probably since it won't support the newer kernel it maybe causing you troubles. In that case just delete your driver with sudo aticonfig --uninstall and unity should work fine with the newer kernel.