# Unity not working after upgrade Ubuntu 13.04 to 14.04

Tags: unity, compiz

The problem is basically that Unity seems broken after an upgrade from 13.04 to 14.04 LTS on x64, so here goes:

1) The Unity logon screen looks strange - e.g. the user names are hardly legible due to poor contrast - but I can still use the screen to log on. The problem described below affects all users.

2) After logging on, the standard Ubuntu wallpaper appears "blank" with no panel and no launcher. There is simply "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" in the bottom left, apparently carried over from the logon screen.

3) I can switch to the text terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

4) There I did a series of fixes found online, such as:

> rm -rf .compiz-1
>   dconf reset -f /org/compiz
>   setsid unity
>   unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
>   export DISPLAY=:0
>   dconf reset -f /org/compiz
>   unity --reset-icons &disown

I also run ccsm and made sure the Unity plug-in and OpenGL are activated.

5) I can now start unity for the current session by entering the command `unity`, but I have to switch to the text terminal and enter `unity` every time I log on now.

6) The output from the "unity" command is as follows:

> **WARNING: no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to :0**
>
> stop: unknown job unity-panel-service
>
> start: unknown job unity-panel-service
>
> compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
>
> compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
>
> compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
>
> compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
>
> compigconfig  - Info: Backend: gsettings
>
> compigconfig  - Info: Integration: true
>
> compigconfig  - Info: Profile: unity
>
> compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
>
> compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
>
> compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: openg1
>
> compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: openg1
>
> compiz (core) - Info: Unity is full supported by your hardware
>
> compiz (core) - Info: Unity is full supported by your hardware
>
> compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: openg1

7) With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> I can switch to the Unity session, where the launcher now works and the standard application icons appear down the left side. But the panel is completely empty. The windows all look kind of "old style" to me (I think).

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: try re-installing it look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/468204/no-panels-or-menus-after-upgrading-to-14-04/468431#468431

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a clean install:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications gir1.2-unity-5.0 unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu libindicator7 indicator-application indicator-datetime indicator-messages libnux-2.0-0 nux-tools libunity-misc4 unity-2d-common

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get install unity unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications gir1.2-unity-5.0 unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu libindicator7 indicator-application indicator-datetime indicator-messages libnux-2.0-0 nux-tools libunity-misc4 unity-2d-common

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I was able to fix a similar issue in the past like this.

Comment: Thks, this worked for me - the logon screen now looks normal and Unity starts fine, including the panel.   Now I have the problem that IBUS starts on logon and the keyboard layout switches to US English, but I guess that is another issue ...