# Unity is not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: unity, 15.10

Today I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10, no errors happened during the upgrade but after the upgrade I can log in using my username and password but unity does not work. No launcher, no panel absolutely nothing just the background.

I tried to start unity myself using `compiz --replace unity` it gives me an error about a missing function definition in `libunity.so` and it fails to load.

Please can you help me with this?

[UPDATE]

output of `sudo apt-cache policy libunity9` is

```
libunity9:
  Installed: 7.1.4+15.10.20151002-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 7.1.4+15.10.20151002-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 7.1.4+15.10.20151002-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

[UPDATE]

After trying to follow the two answers the error message has changed as follows

`DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace unity` outputs to standard error

```
  compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
  compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
  Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keycompiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display :0
  compiz (core) - Info: Stopping plugin: core
  compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: core
```

Comment: After following the two answers, the problem was solved by following the answer to this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/131016/how-can-i-remove-and-re-install-unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have an answer already, try a fresh install of Unity.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications gir1.2-unity-5.0 unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu libindicator7 indicator-application indicator-datetime indicator-messages libnux-2.0-0 nux-tools libunity-misc4 unity-2d-common`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get autoclean`

`sudo apt-get install unity unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications gir1.2-unity-5.0 unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu libindicator7 indicator-application indicator-datetime indicator-messages libnux-2.0-0 nux-tools libunity-misc4 unity-2d-common`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

This should restore Unity.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/478126/unity-not-working-after-upgrade-ubuntu-13-04-to-14-04?rq=1)

Comment: This did not work.

Answer (score 6):

Reinstalling didn't work for me, as the problem was due to specific user files (`~/.`)

To get back your Unity launcher after an upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10, you can just open a virtual terminal `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, log in and then:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
cd ~
rm  -rf .gconf .gconfd .compiz .config/compiz .config/dconf
sudo service lightdm restart
```

That's all, it worked for me! My old installation had probably messed up user files, so removing them did the trick.

Comment: This did not work.

Comment: Yeah, clearing old config files usually help.

Comment: This didn't help. Still have to open terminal and run `setsid unity`.

Comment: After spending hours on removing & installing unity, this solution solved my problem. I also found `.config/compiz-1` and I removed it. Check for this folders as well and remove them. Thanks again for your solution.