# Right click "open terminal" option no longer on desktop after breaking and fixing Unity

Tags: unity, gnome-terminal

The right click menu on my desktop no longer has an option to launch the terminal.

Brief history: I was messing around with my locale file and ended up breaking unity. There was no desktop, no launcher, no menu bar after booting up. I managed to restore unity by following the top two answers here: [unity is not working after upgrade to ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692204/unity-is-not-working-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-15-10)

But after that my terminal disappeared. It appeared in my dash search but wouldn't open. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>, the option in the right click menu: nothing worked.

So I removed and reinstalled gnome-terminal. But the option from the right click menu has stayed absent.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing these:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

Also, you have to restart or restart nautilus with the `-q` parameter