# When I log in there is nothing except the default wallpaper, is there anything I can do?

Tags: crash

Last night I was browsing the internet while I had VLC and a text document open, suddenly the screen jumped to VLC with the text document in front of it. The video was playable and the document editable but the I couldn't move the document or do anything else. I restart the computer and everything is normal until I log in then there is just the default wallpaper(I had changed the wallpaper) and that is it, no icons no nothing. Is there anything I can do or is reinstalling necessary. I was on Ubuntu 14.04 My other operating system is OS X 10.7.5

Comment: Like your name here @Blank :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: you can check my workaround here http://askubuntu.com/questions/468204/no-panels-or-menus-after-upgrading-to-14-04/468431#468431

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to open tty. Here, run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity ubuntu-desktop`. After that finishes, run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` before rebooting.

Comment: @BlankDesktop Please click the Tick if this solved your to mark it as accepted!

Answer (score -2):

First, restart X with this command:

```
sudo -S restart lightdm
```

Sometimes this is a quick fix for running processes.

Comment: Whenever I do this, I'm always left with a black screen and a blinking cursor; it doesn't work.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I've been using this command like for years and it always works there's probably smth's wrong with your graphics configuration. Though this command basically useless to the OP.

Comment: @JoKeR I've used it on many computers and it's just never worked for me. I don't know.

Comment: did you try it from terminal or a console? Sometimes it might make a difference I always run it from console.