# 14.04.3 Login screen loop Graphic card failure

Tags: 14.04, unity, graphics, login, lightdm

I'm running 14.04.3 on a ASUS Netbook X201E. Today, I was'nt able to login to my account. `lightdm` starts abnormally. The top bar is'nt displayed. After attempting to log in with correct password (tested, if incorrect password reply works), pixel errors appearing and the login screen comes up again. Guest login doesn't wrk either. Networking, ssh access etc. works.
I purged and reinstalled `lightdm`, then I installed and started `gdm`. Problem persists. Guest login worked once but displayed a Low graphics mode warning window, but this was'nt readable. Only got some orange tick boxes appearing when hovering the mouse. This issue also appeared several times during the last couple of days after logging in to unity.

```
root@****-X201EP:/var/crash# ls -al
drwxrwsrwt  2 root    whoopsie    4096 Sep  7 16:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root    root        4096 Okt 18  2013 ..
-rw-------  1 root    whoopsie  117560 Sep  7 14:54 lightdm.0.crash
-rw-rw----  1 root    whoopsie       0 Sep  7 14:26 .lock
-rw-r-----  1 ****   whoopsie   57834 Sep  7 15:09 _    opt_extras.ubuntu.com_my-weather-indicator_bin_my-weather-    indicator.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 ****   whoopsie 3819201 Sep  7 14:50     _usr_bin_compiz.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 gdm     whoopsie 3686538 Sep  7 15:10     _usr_bin_compiz.124.crash
-rw-r-----  1     125 whoopsie 3671372 Sep  7 16:08     _usr_bin_compiz.125.crash
-rw-r-----  1 lightdm whoopsie 1259692 Sep  7 14:39 _usr_bin_nm-    applet.110.crash
----------  1 gdm     whoopsie  294598 Sep  7 14:52 _usr_bin_nm-    applet.124.crash
```

Excerpt from `lightdm.0.crash` containing errors, which seems relevant to me:

```
(gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0:12099): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Cannot open     pixbuf loader module file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

 This likely means that your installation is broken.
 Try running the command
   gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-    2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
 to make things work again for the time being.
```

My graphics:

```
****@****-X201EP:/var/crash$ grep -i chipset /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[  3094.913] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
[  3094.914] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  3094.916] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 2000

****@****-X201EP:/var/crash$ dmesg |grep -i agp
[    0.000000] No AGP bridge found
[    0.000000] No AGP bridge found
[    1.354888] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
```

Output from `sudo lshw -c video`:

```
*-display
       Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
       Produkt: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 2
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:02.0
       Version: 09
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       FÃ¤higkeiten: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       Konfiguration: driver=i915 latency=0
       Ressourcen: irq:41 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-    
efffffff ioport:f000(GrÃ¶Ãe=64)
```

`ubuntu-drivers devices` is:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000014E4d00004727sv00001A3Bsd00002047bc02sc80i00
model    : BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
vendor   : Broadcom Corporation
driver   : bcmwl-kernel-source - distro non-free
```

Shall I update my video drivers? Already added `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/637699/448428) worked for me!!
Did 
`chown username:username .Xauthority`
and
`sudo chmod a+wt /tmp`

Unity issue seems to be resolved as well.