# Ubuntu 16.04 Login Loop/no launcher nvidia

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, login, 16.04

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 15 (.10 I think) to Ubuntu 16.04, and had the login loop issue (where I would enter my password, press enter and then it would take me right back to login screen, same thing for guest too). After consulting the internet, I was able to remove nvidia drivers and get the login to work (also my second monitor, which at first I thought it was a settings issue). The problem now is that I dont have the launcher or the menu bar, the fix for that aparently is installing the nvidia drivers, which causes the login loop issue. Everything else seems to work fine (I am able to launch programs through the terminal, which is how I am running firefox right now). Of course I would prefer to have nvidia drivers over generic since I found them to work better for graphics intensive process's.

Thanks!

EDIT: After messing around with secure boot (I seem to have left the same settings as when I started so I dont really know what is different) it seems like I am able to login with nvidia-361 drivers installed, but I still dont have the launcher or the menu bar

Comment: take a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/468204/no-panels-or-menus-after-upgrading-to-14-04/468431#468431

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix it by messing around with BIOS (not sure what I did, I went back to the same settings I had and login worked). Configuring CCSM took care of the launcher.